# Sceneform load my model without basecolor texture

Tags: android-studio, arcore, gltf, sceneform, glblendfunc

First I test my model .gltf with sceneform 1.5 and it looks very good:

[image: mobile screenshot]

But when I use sceneform 1.17.1 or 1.15, the color of the gltf model is gone and it looks like this:

[image: mobile screenshot]

I tried .glb and it's no different.

But I got some .glb models from the Internet and it worked perfectly in my app.

I exported my file from 3dmax and babylon.js and blender and they are not working....
Can anybody help me please?

Comment: I think i found the problem where ever i have roughness the basecolor not show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the model from 3d max by .obj format and import to blender then exported as .glb and its worke